# Subcategories from skos:broader, include parent category

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Why in the following query, the `Category:American_architecture_by_state`  is listed in the results?

```
 select distinct ?s where { ?s skos:broader category:Architecture_in_Alabama}
```

[image]

Isn't `category:American_architecture_by_state`, supposed to be  `category:Architecture_in_Alabama`'s  parent category not subcategory?

This is really messing up my results when I use skos:broader* as I expect it to start from Parent node and traverse to child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> *This is really messing up my results when I use skos:broader as I
>   expect it to start from Parent node and traverse to child nodes.*

I'm not sure what you expect that.  The definition of skos:broader is given in [§8 Semantic Relations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-skos-reference-20090818/#semantic-relations) in the SKOS standard:

> ### [8. Semantic Relations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-skos-reference-20090818/#semantic-relations)
>
> The properties skos:broader and skos:narrower are used to assert a
>   direct hierarchical link between two SKOS concepts. **A triple A
>   skos:broader B asserts that B, the object of the triple, is a
>   broader concept than A, the subject of the triple.** Similarly, a
>   triple C skos:narrower D asserts that D, the object of the
>   triple, is a narrower concept than C, the subject of the triple.

That means that the query

```
select distinct ?s where {
  ?s skos:broader category:Architecture_in_Alabama
}
```

should select categories that are *narrower* than **category:Architecture_in_Alabama**.  Now, I'd agree that it seems like Architecture in America by State might be a supercategory of Architecture in Alabama, but it's important to note that categories aren't the same kind of things as classes.  If A is a subclass of B, then everything that is an A is also B.  That's not how categories work, though.

> #### 8.6.6. skos:broader and Transitivity
>
> Note that skos:broader is not a transitive property. Similarly,
>   skos:narrower is not a transitive property.

> #### 8.6.8. Cycles in the Hierarchical Relation (skos:broaderTransitive and Reflexivity)
>
> In the graph below, a cycle has been stated in the hierarchical
>   relation. Note that this graph is consistent with the SKOS data model,
>   i.e., there is no condition requiring that skos:broaderTransitive be
>   irreflexive.
>
> Example 37 (consistent)
>
> ```
> <A> skos:broader <B> .
> <B> skos:broader <A> .
> ```

What it looks like might actually be the case is that the **American architecture by state** category is broader than most of the "Architecture in XXX" categories, **and vice versa**.  E.g., look at the [DBpedia page for **American architecture by state**](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:American_architecture_by_state);  note that it has (just as one example) Architecture_in_New_York as a value of broader, but it also a value of broader *for* is skos:broader of Architecture_in_New_York.  I agree that it's kind of weird, possibly undesirable, but it's not disallowed:

> [For] many applications where knowledge organization systems are used, a
>   cycle in the hierarchical relation represents a potential problem. For
>   these applications, computing the transitive closure of
>   skos:broaderTransitive then looking for statements of the form X
>   skos:broaderTransitive X is a convenient strategy for finding cycles
>   in the hierarchical relation. How an application should handle such
>   statements is not defined in this specification and may vary between
>   applications.

Comment: Very informative comments Joshua, Thanks but do you happen to know a work around for this case?  when  ?subcat skos:broader* ?parent  , a provision that would not allow any ?subcat to be broader or equal  the root node (?parent in this case). Is it possible? Also something that would filter all ?subcat  that are reflexive, in terms of skos:broader.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Category:American_architecture_by_state` is both present in `skis:broader` and its inverse `is skos:broader of`. The query is working perfectly well, if you don't want `Category:American_architecture_by_state` in your result set, you need to rethink your query.

Comment: I know, but it should only be present in  skos:broader of. Even intuitively it does not make sense for something to be present in both skos:broader and skos:broader_of